# Como impedir Python de considerar números muito próximos iguais?

Tags: python

Fiz esse algoritmo para testar como Python compara números próximos:

```
x = 2.5                                # número arbitrário que escolhi para fazer os testes
y = float(input('Insira o Y '))        #
print('X > Y = {}'.format(x > y))      # mostra se x>y
print('X = Y = {}'.format(x == y))     # mostra se x = y
print('X < Y = {}'.format(x < y))      # mostra se x < y
```

Para y = 2.50000000000000001, por exemplo, Python retorna que X = Y.

```
Insira o Y 2.50000000000000001
X > Y = False
X = Y = True
X < Y = False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Como fazer o Python perceber que X é menor que Y, parando de arredondar?

Comment: Leia [Aritmética de ponto flutuante: Problemas e limitações](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso parece ser um problema de precisão do `float`. Ao executar o termninal do Python e colar o valor `2.50000000000000001`, é retornado `2.5`.

Para solucionar, utilize a classe `Decimal`.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

x = 2.5
y = Decimal(input('Insira o Y '))        
print('X > Y = {}'.format(x > y))      # false
print('X = Y = {}'.format(x == y))     # false
print('X < Y = {}'.format(x < y))      # true
```